# How to change screen using stackNavigation in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have one screen which in header consists button to go to another screen.

I have already model here, but it doesn't work: As shown below I want to change the screen from RecipeList to NewRecipeForm using Button in header

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
 List: {
  screen: RecipesList,
  navigationOptions: {
    title:'RecipesList',
    headerLeft: (
      <Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('NewRecipeForm')}>
      <Text>+</Text>
      </Button>
    )
    }},
 NewRecipeForm: {screen: CreateRecipeForm, 
        navigationOptions: {title:'Add new recipe'}},
  Details: {screen: RecipesDetails, navigationOptions: {title:'RecipeDetails'}},

export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return <AppStackNavigator initialRouteName='List' />;
   }
}
```

> I hope that you will help me with solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use your stack navigator as like below, you can able to destructure your navigation property while giving your navigationOptions property as well in the createStackNavigator itself

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    List: {
        screen: RecipesList,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {  //destructure the navigation property here 
            return {
                title: 'RecipesList',
                headerLeft: (
                    <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewRecipeForm')}>
                        <Text>+</Text>
                    </Button>
                )
            }
        }
    },
    NewRecipeForm: {
        screen: CreateRecipeForm,
        navigationOptions: { title: 'Add new recipe' }
    },
    Details: { screen: RecipesDetails, navigationOptions: { title: 'RecipeDetails' } }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the props of your component in headerLeft, but you can directly use the navigation like this :

```
  <Button onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('NewRecipeForm')}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code inside your RecipesList Component instead of having it inside createStackNavigator(). See this [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@dinithminura/navigation-from-header-button) for full implementation.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: "RecipesList",
      headerLeft: (
        <Button
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewRecipeForm')}
          title="+"
        />
      ),
    };
  };
```